# md-menus not closing when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-menu-bar>
  <md-menu ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <md-button class="navButton" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
      {{section.name}}
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>Subsection 1</md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
</md-menu-bar>
```

I am doing something like above but unfortunately, if I click a menu, it stays open even if I click other buttons.

I just want it to have the same behaviour as

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar

P.S. If I don't use ng-repeat (meaning, menus are static), it works fine though.

[**Problem Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gpygja?editors=101)

Comment: Directive ng-repeat creates a separate scope, that's why (most likely) your example works. One possibility is to use controllerAs syntax and assigning your method onto real directive controller scope, not angular $scope. You'd then access in your method opening new menu as ctrlName.methodName(); It would be easier if you created a fiddle

Comment: Pankaj created a codepen. Thank you very much! @Maciej, Please see edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just bumped into this question and noticed that the link posted by S.Klechkovski has a workaround made by christrude. It's not perfect (as other users pointed out) but at least it works. Might as well post it here.

You have to include the `$mdMenu` service in your controller and invoke its `hide` method when you click to open the menu.

```
$scope.closeOthers = function() {
  $mdMenu.hide(null, { closeAll: true });
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<button ng-click="closeOthers();$mdOpenMenu()">File</button>
```

Here's an edited [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYvvNo). I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

The best solution is patching the component itself. Even with the disadvantages with the workaround found in Github (that I replicated here) it's still the best one.

However here's an alternative just for exploration purposes ;) [This little frankenstein](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyQQYg) uses promises to only open the next menu when all the animations are done.

**Markup**

```
<button ng-click="closeOthers().then($mdOpenMenu);">File</button>
```

**Controller**

```
var lock = false;

$scope.closeOthers = function() {
  if(lock) {
    return;
  }

  var defer = $q.defer()
  lock = true;

  $mdMenu.hide(null, { closeAll: true }).then(function() {
    lock = false;
    defer.resolve();
  });

  return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a complete working solution although it is good enough in some cases. The issue with this solution is that when you try menu1->menu2->menu1 again, the `md-content` will be not be displayed because as it is opening, it was still hit by the `.hide()`

Comment: @ReyLibutan I made an edit but I still think the other one is the best you'll get without fixing the component (either waiting for official fix, or running a patched component which may be undesirable for you).

Answer (score 2):

Good question! It seems that is known bug which is not yet fixed. I have added a comment with your example and some elaboration of the problem on the existing [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4484#issuecomment-149373027). Let's hope that it will be fixed soon.

Comment:

> Here is an example [Codepen](http://goo.gl/MEl6wV) that illustrates the reported issue.
>
> After some research I noticed that it happens because md-menu
>   directives use $scope.$emit for triggering the $mdMenuOpen event on
>   which listen all md-menu instances. $emit triggers listeners on all
>   parent scopes including the one on which the event is emitted. That
>   means if all md-menu instances are on the same scope everything is
>   fine but that is not the case with ng-repeat which creates new scope
>   for each child.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable workaround I found was

```
$scope.forceCloseMenu = function () {
    $('.md-open-menu-container').hide();
    $('.md-menu-backdrop').remove();
    $('.md-scroll-mask').remove();
};
```

And calling forceCloseMenu() every time a menu item was clicked.

Note this requires jQuery also.